# Origins of "aluminium"

Tags: etymology

What are the roots of the word *aluminium*?

I am interested since English and Americans spell the word differently (with and without the final *i* respectively).

**Edit**: If *aluminum* was the original word and was later amended to *aluminium* (as OpaCitiZen states below), why did the change take place? There are other elements which end in *-um* rather than *-ium* (e.g. *platinum*). Also, why was the change not universal?

Comment: -1 and flagged as general reference.

Comment: @Hugo Really? Care to explain why?

Comment: Here's the close reason: "This question is too basic; it can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information." The single answer shows it's general reference by linking to an etymological dictionary. See also [Are Some Questions Too Simple?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/)

Comment: It looks to me that this has been answered adequately by a single link.

Comment: Still seems an incomplete argument to me. Why rename "aluminum", but not "platinum"? I've edited the question now. Hope you don't still think that's "too basic" for you, Hugo ;-)

Comment: @Urbycoz The "platinum" question is a different question and not something your original question addressed; I'm not sure this moving of goalposts is a good idea. In any case the "platinum" question would also most likely be closed since there's no way of answering it in a non speculative way.

Comment: I can't win. The question is too basic, but elaborating is seen as "moving the goalposts". Ho hum!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1812, coined by English chemist Sir Humphry Davy (1778-1829), from L.
>   *alumen* "alum" (see *alum*). Davy originally called it *alumium* (1808),
>   then amended this to *aluminum*, which remains the U.S. word, but
>   British editors in 1812 further amended it to *aluminium*, the modern
>   preferred British form, to better harmonize with other element names
>   (*sodium*, *potassium*, etc.).
>
> > Aluminium, for so we shall take the liberty of writing the word, in preference to aluminum, which has a less classical sound. ["Quarterly Review," 1812]

source: [**etymonline**.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Aluminium&searchmode=none)

Comment: "a less classical sound"- how odd. So it essentially just "sounded" better. I imagined it was derived from Latin, Greek or such like.

Comment: @Urbycoz Yes, pretty much! Aluminum sounds like a Latin -um word (Latin is "classical"), but aluminium sounds like other existing element names (e.g. sodium, potassium).

Comment: Wonder why they didn't do the same for others (e.g. "Platinum")